# How to "Auto Generate" String in Sequence from "0-9 A-Z"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to auto generate string from 0-9 and A-z.

00001-99999
A0001-A9999
B0001-B9999
Z9999-AA999
AB001-ZZ999
AAA01-.....

And in sequence

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post at least your tries. We are not here to do your homework

Answer (score 0):

just make a recursive call to a function.

```
list=[]
for i in range(10):
    list.append(str(i))
for i in range(26):
    list.append(chr(ord('a')+i))
def all(pre,n):
    li=[]
    if n==1:
        for x in list:
            for p in pre:
                li.append(x+p)
        return li
    else:
        for x in list:
            for p in pre:
                li.append(x+p)
        return all(li,n-1)
print(all([''],2))
```

Recursor may take a lot of time for large numbers, so you can also make your own number system to increment.

```
class NumSys:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val=[0,0,0,0,0]
    def next(self):
        self.val[4]+=1
        for i in range(5):
            if self.val[4-i]>35:
                if i==4:
                    return None
                else:
                    self.val[4-i-1]+=1
                    self.val[4-i]-=35
    def __str__(self):
        stri=''
        for i in range(5):
            x=self.val[i]
            if x<10:
                stri+=str(x)
            else:
                stri+=chr(ord('a')+x-10)
        return stri

n=NumSys()
for i in range(100):
    print (str(n))
    n.next()
```